# How can I record the number of else events in a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to record and use the number of else occurrences in a simple function.
The function works, I can see the right answers in the console; however I want now to use the number of occurrences in any of the options. For example, if I get 10 times 'its not a letter', I want to have this 10 as a number to be placed in a field using innerHTML. How can I do that?

```
function checkLetters() {
    if (character == Letter) {
        console.log('Its a letter');
    } else {
        console.log('Its not a letter');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ignoring the case issue and undefined variables in your example; keeping track of the count means you need a variable.  And since you want it to count up to 10, that would suggest it would be scoped outside of the function.

Comment: Show your code - including the 'field' where you expect to use innerHTML.....  As a function only, there is a LOT missing to do what you want....

Comment: Hi, I want it to count infinity, not only to 10. I want basically the number of occurrences to be recorded as it is shown on the console. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can increase a variable in the `else` statement.

```
let numOfElse = 0;

function checkLetters() {
  if (character == Letter) {
    console.log('Its a letter');
  } else {
    console.log('Its not a letter');
    numOfElse ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I got it guys! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

HTML

```
<span id="not-a-letter">0</span>
```

JavaScript

```
var itsNotALetter = 0;

function checkLetters() {
    if (character == Letter) {
        console.log('Its a letter');
    } else {
        console.log('Its not a letter');
        itsNotALetter++;
    }

    document.getElementById('not-a-letter').innerHTML = itsNotALetter;
 }
```